# Mpdf 7 pagebreak html bug with hidden and margin header

Tags: mpdf, page-break

Mpdf with some general parameters :

```
$this->SetDisplayMode("fullwidth",'single');
$this->autoPageBreak=true;
$this->setAutoTopMargin='pad';
$this->setAutoBottomMargin='pad';
```

Mpdf header parameters :

```
$this->DefHTMLHeaderByName("myHeader1","<div>HEADER<br>HEADER<br>HEADER<br>HEADER<br>HEADER<br>HEADER<br>HEADER<br></div>");
$this->SetHTMLHeaderByName("myHeader1",'O');
```

Example code html with WriteHTML :

```
<table><tbody><tr><td></td></tr></tbody></table>
<br>
<pagebreak even-footer-value="1" even-header-value="-1" odd-footer-value="1" even-header-name="myHeader2" odd-header-value="-1" type="NEXT-ODD"></pagebreak>
<div>sfndjkhsfjsf</div>
```

Result PDF with 2 pages and on the second page the margin is not respected. The header is removed but not its height. In version Mpdf 6 this bug was not present :
[click pdf example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqUDF.png)

How to correct this error ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: The mPDF initialisation code you've included doesn't show the mirror margins (https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-variables/mirrormargins.html) configuration option. If this setting is disabled (is by default), you don't have "odd" or "even" pages / headers. That could be a cause of your problem.

Comment: i put mirrormargins=1, the margin in the second page is good ... but the pdf document add one empty page between the first and second page.

Comment: I specify that this code worked in version 6.1

Comment: Many bugs have been fixed in version 7. This sounds like one of them. Regarding the extra page, as per the documentation, `type="NEXT-ODD"` will add multiple pages if required to get you that next odd / even page. See http://mpdf.github.io/reference/html-control-tags/pagebreak.html